# Не могу найти путь к данным iCloud на Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль, apple

Надо указать в Obsidian путь к данной папке Obsidian из iCloud Drive, не нашел как найти путь к данным.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как ты ставил прогу?

Comment: iCloud в ubuntu software скачал и залогинился

Comment: А если переутсновить в классическом режиме `sudo snap install icloud-for-linux --classic`?